# Type 'Headers' is missing the following properties from type 'Headers': keys, values, toJSON, getAll, and 2 more

Tags: ionic3

I am using the following code to send headers in **POST** request :

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Accept", 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' );
headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));

const requestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

return this.http.post(this.url, postData, requestOptions) .map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
  data => {
    console.log(data);
  },
  err => {
    console.log("ERROR!: ", err);
  }
);
```

But the **{headers: headers}** is displaying the error :

> Type 'Headers' is missing the following properties from type 'Headers': keys, values, toJSON, getAll, and 2 more.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you have found the answer for this, but I will provide it anyway for future reference - I have experienced the same problem.

And by just ensuring that `var headers : Headers`, headers is type Headers.

It is important to note that the interface `RequestOptionsArgs.headers` expects type `Headers` and not `HttpHeaders`, so you should mix the two.

To get around this you must user `Headers`:

```
let _requestOptions : RequestOptions = new RequestOptions(
{
    { headers: new Headers({})
});
```

Or you can have the Headers as a variable like you did and pass it to the `headers : //here`

Answer (score 0):

```
  const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Accept': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'Content-Type':  'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Basic' + btoa(username + ":" + password)
        })
      };
   return this.http.post(this.url, postData, httpOptions ) .map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
      },
      err => {
        console.log("ERROR!: ", err);
      }
    );
```

And import HttpHeaders above like

```
import { HttpClient,HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Comment: It gives another error : **Argument of type 'HttpHeaders' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestOptionsArgs'.
  Property 'headers' is private in type 'HttpHeaders' but not in type 'RequestOptionsArgs'.**

Comment: then your dont need to put **Httpheaders** to **RequestOptions** just take one variable and then declare it on your url,I have **Edited** my answer so check it i,tried and tested

Comment: @AniruddhThakor it doesn't work for me. Could you please suggest something else?

Answer (score 0):

For me this solved this issue: *(tested on Angular >= 9)*

I was doing a basic mistake, I was using (private http: Http) in constructor
// * this is deprecated and throws err as mentioned in OP

**Working method:** 
*authentication.service.ts*

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
...
@Injectable() export class AuthService {
 
 // ! include http client
 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

// * login method
login(userDetails) {
     const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'x-auth-header': 'auth token' });
     return this.http.post(url, userDetails, 
     { headers: headers }).pipe(map(
     response => {return response;}
  ));
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error message because I was creating a new `HttpHeaders` object when the existing code was using just `Headers`. Once I converted all the typing into `HttpHeaders` the problem resolved.